# Why can I push into a Readable stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I was using a piece of code similar to this until I discovered the 'setEncoding' method. While refactoring the code, this question came to me.

```
readable.push(chunk, 'base64')
readable.push(null)
readable.pipe(res)
```

Isn't pushing a form of writing data? Shouldn't I be unable to write any data into a Readable stream? I know that every data needs to be written (otherwise it would be null) and read (or it becomes useless) at some point, but I thought Node would abstract that from us.

Could someone clear this up for me? 
Thanks

Comment: I also feel that is confusing, so to push is to output as readable steam is a data source outputting data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This comes into play when you're creating a new Readable Stream from scratch. A Readable Stream needs to begin somewhere and there needs to be a way to get data into that new Stream. When doing a `push()` like in your question, you're buffering data until it is read at which point it is then flushed from the stream and then piped/read into the destination for consumption. The consumer will continue reading the data until 'null' is hit which indicates the stream is done outputting data.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var readable = new stream.Readable(); // new empty stream.Readable
readable.push('some data');
readable.push(null); // Done writing data
```

To get the fullest picture on how streams work under the hood and the various types of streams, you should read the [Stream Handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook/blob/master/readme.markdown) by Substack. That should answer any lingering questions you might have.

Comment: Just one more thing: Is this way of creating Readables async?

Comment: The async aspect of Node really only comes into play when you're performing an operation that is I/O bound. Node is single threaded and only can do things one at a time, async operations are handled by libuv which creates the multithreaded feel of node. However, this isn't a blocking operation meaning async operations can still be handled while this code is executing.

Comment: After reading the docs, everything makes more sense: "end <Boolean> End the writer when the reader ends. Defaults to true." There's the writer and the reader of a stream, and when the writer ends, no more data can be written to a Readable. That's what pushing null makes.